# how to store multiple check boxes with single name in one cell of the mysql data base in php.?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, validation, checkbox

`
        ENQUIRY FORM

```
  <div class="row">
      <label class="col-md-3" for="zones">Zones in Bangalore</label>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <p id="zones"><input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" class="zones">CBD 
          <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" class="zones">North 
          <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" class="zones">South  
          <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" class="zones">East  
          <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" class="zones">West</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-3" for="propertytype">Property Type</label>
        <div class="checkboxes">
          <p id="propertytype">
            <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype[]" class="propertytype">Apartment &nbsp;

            <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype[]" class="propertytype">Raw House &nbsp;

            <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype[]" class="propertytype">Villa  &nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype[]" class="propertytype">Residential Plot</p>
        </div>

      </div>

$('.zones').on('change', function() {
      $('.zones').not(this).prop('checked', false);
       });
      $('.propertytype').on('change', function() {
        $('.propertytype').not(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
```

this is the code the script code selects only one check box. i am not able figure out how to store this check box values. i am getting error while trying to store this data. I have tried to check for if condition but not able to get the code. i have 4 more similar check boxes in my project and i have to store all the data in a single database table. can you please help me to solve the problem.

In controller:

```
  $numreg= '/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/';
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('zones[]', 'zones of Bangalore',   'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('propertytype[]', 'Property type', 'required');

       }

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
           {
             $data_to_store = array(

               'zones'=> $_POST['zones'],
               'propertytype'=> $_POST['propertytype']

          );

       $this->db->insert('enquiry', $data_to_store);
     }`
```

Comment: What's the error shows up?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 553

Comment: You could try vinothini answer :)

Comment: at a time i am selecting only one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your checkbox values and can store it in your table.

Like below:

```
$data_to_store = array(

           'zones'=> serialize($_POST['zones']),
           'propertytype'=> serialize($_POST['propertytype'])

      );
```

You can unserialize datas back by `unserialize()` which is a php functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach for each data stored in db if both the arrays have same length.

```
$data_to_store = array(
    'zones' => $this->input->post('zones'),
    'propertytype' => $this->input->post('propertytype')
);
$data = array();
foreach($data_to_store['zones'] as $keyZone => $valZone)
{
    $data['zone'] = $valZone;
    $data['propertytype'] = $this->input->post('propertytype')[$keyZone];
    $this->db->insert('enquiry', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your checkboxes values to save or you'll get back an array without context.

```
<p id="zones">
  <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="CBD" class="zones">CBD 
  <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="North" class="zones">North 
  <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="South" class="zones">South  
  <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="East" class="zones">East  
  <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="West" class="zones">West
</p>
```

If you want to save all the zones in one table field you could use implode() to create a semi-colon separated list.

```
 $myZones = implode( ';' , $_POST['zones'] );

 print_r($myZones); // North;East;West
```

And do the same thing for propertytype as well.

EDIT: Re-read question that you're only giving back one checkbox per array. In which case, implode() will still work since it doesn't insert the semi-colon if there's only one array element.

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
         $data_to_store = array(

           'zones'=> implode(';', $_POST['zones']), // South
           'propertytype'=> implode(';', $_POST['propertytype']) // Apartment
      );

   $this->db->insert('enquiry', $data_to_store);
 };
```

EDIT 2: If your db `insert` is blowing up because of the array to string conversion, use json_encode to convert the array first.

```
 $data_to_store = array('zones' => 'South', 'propertytype' => 'Apartment');

 $db_value = json_encode($data_to_store);

 print_r($db_value); // {"zones":"South","propertytype":"Apartment"}

 $this->db->insert('enquiry', $db_value);
```